# Primefaces ColourPicker, how to get ajax event of change

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'd like to have the colour selected from a Primefaces ColourPicker sent to my backend on change.

This seems not to be supported though.

```
  <p:colorPicker value="#{colorView.colorPopup}" />
```

I can see it will submit the value when the page is submitted.

```
  <p:colorPicker value="#{colorView.colorPopup}" />
  <p:commandButton value="Submit" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show();" update="grid" />
```

Even some Javascript being called on change would be great.

---

Update:

I would like the backing bean to updated on colour change, not just when I submit the form.

The main reason for this is that I have several colourpickers on the page and the form is submitted I don't know which value is from which colour picker.

Comment: Do you want to perform some actions besides setting the `colorPopup` value? Or is it that you have tested this and believe that the value is not updated before a non-ajax submit ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having an ajax call `onChange` of the colorPicker is a bad idea, you might end up with 100 queued ajax calls as the user is picking the color by dragging the selector in the color palette.

Therefor `onHide` would serve better in that case, I'll demonstrate the two events implementations and I do recommend the `onHide`

*onChange*

```
var oldOnChange = PF('colorPickerWV').cfg.onChange;
$(document.body).children('.ui-colorpicker-container').data('colorpicker').onChange =
function(b,d,c) {
   oldOnChange.apply(this, [b,d,c]);
   console.log('valueChanged:should be remoteCommand with process of the colorPicker');
 };
```

*onHide*

```
var oldOnHide = PF('colorPickerWV').cfg.onHide;
$(document.body).children('.ui-colorpicker-container').data('colorpicker').onHide = 
   function(b) {
      oldOnHide.apply(this, [b]);
      console.log('Panel is hidden: should be remoteCommand with process of the colorPicker');
};
```

`colorPickerWV` is the widgetVar name

And here's the `this` object

[image]

Comment: You could add a timeout in the onChange, so a change will only be send to the server every x miliseconds

Comment: Even if you add a setTimeout, still you are queuing those ajax requests but with a bit delay !

Comment: No, since only when the timeout fires you do a remotecommand. On each onChange you reset the timeout. If I have it working, I'll post an example

Comment: Even if you reset the timeout, the back-end at some point won't have a consisting value!

Comment: Sorry, when might that happen? PrimeFaces spinner does the same

Comment: I might have missed that angle, I'll check the code of the spinner  :)

Comment: I had a look into the script of the spinner, there's nothing related to a timeout, the change event is being called on each [change](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/b2c095571eb81ac9ff6dd3180630e7f6c4fad115/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/spinner/spinner.js#L55)

Comment: No, not if you keep the button pressed…  only when releasing, an event is send.

Comment: Ok, it works a 'little' differently, by using the keyup to... I have a full example. Will post it below, not to have a better aswer, but just for information

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onChange` eventhandler and by adding a timeout that is reset on each 'change' and that only fires after x miliseconds of no change (250 in this case), it works perfectly. Keep in mind that I used the widgetVar value of the component here to, to have it work on specific ColorPickers in your page, not automagically all of them.

```
var oldonChange = PF(widgetVar).cfg.onChange;
$(document.body).children('.ui-colorpicker-container').each(
    function(i, element) {
        var overlay = $(element), options = overlay.data('colorpicker');
        if (options.id == PF(widgetVar).id) {
            _self = PF(widgetVar);
            options.onChange = function(a, b, c) {
                oldonChange.apply(_self, [a, b, c ]);
                clearTimeout(_self.submitTimer);
                _self.submitTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                    console
                       .log('Data is changed: should be remoteCommand with process of the colorPicker')
                    //The call below is what the name of the remote command is
                    //window[widgetVar+"_change"]();

                }, 250);
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have several colorpickers you can do it like this:

```
document.body.onload = function() {
    $(".ui-colorpicker-container").each(function() {
        $(this).data('colorpicker').onHide = 
            function() {
                updateMiniPreview();
            }
        })      
};
```

The "updateMiniPreview" function is a p:remoteCommand which updates the target area:

```
<p:remoteCommand update="miniPreview" name="updateMiniPreview" />
```